# Group php array by two fields

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to create a single array result after it filters object by `service` field and `type` field and sum `taskCount` and `usageTime`fields.

This is the array I want to group:

```
        [
            ["service" => "creatives", "type" => "HTMLToImage", "taskCount" => 418, "usageTime" => 7860],
            ["service" => "displayads", "type" => "html5", "taskCount" => 147, "usageTime" => 3865],
            ["service" => "creatives", "type" => "HTMLToVideo", "taskCount" => 543, "usageTime" => 8549],
            ["service" => "displayads", "type" => "html5", "taskCount" => 321, "usageTime" => 5423]
        ];
```

So far I have tried this method:

```
            $myArr = array_reduce($myArr, function($carry, $item) { 
                if(!isset($carry[$item->service])) {
                    $carry[$item->service] = $item;
                } else {
                    $carry[$item->service]->taskCount += $item->taskCount;
                    $carry[$item->service]->totalDuration += $item->totalDuration;
                }
                return $carry;
            });
            
            $myArr = array_values($myArr);
```

Result:

```
        [
            ["service" => "creatives", "type" => "HTMLToImage", "taskCount" => 961, "usageTime" => 16403],
            ["service" => "displayads", "type" => "html5", "taskCount" => 468, "usageTime" => 9288]
        ];
```

As you can see `"type" => "HTMLToVideo"` consumed by `HTMLtoImage` type...

Expected Result:

```
        [
            ["service" => "creatives", "type" => "HTMLToImage", "taskCount" => 418, "usageTime" => 7860],
            ["service" => "creatives", "type" => "HTMLToVideo", "taskCount" => 961, "usageTime" => 8549],
            ["service" => "displayads", "type" => "html5", "taskCount" => 468, "usageTime" => 9288]
        ];
```

thanks.

Comment: What result do you expect to obtain? Btw I'd go with a foreach, much easier to read and to maintain...

Comment: At the end of the question, I gave the expected result

Comment: In your expected result, why are the two `"service" => "creatives", "type" => "HTMLToImage"` not grouped?

Comment: _“As you can see "type" => "HTMLToVideo" consumed by HTMLtoImage type”_ - it got “consumed”, because you are using _only_ `$carry[$item->service]` to assemble your data under. You are not even taking your second grouping criterion into account there at all.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to take the second criterion but the results are starting to become pretty silly. I tried many methods, but I could not get the result I wanted. I thought that if I presented it this way, maybe I could lay a better foundation for someone who could help.

Comment: @brombeer I'm sorry, you're right I edited that part.

Comment: You will either need to use a two-dimensional array to collect your data in (and then transform that into the flat structure you want afterwards), or you combine both values into _one_ key value to use for your $carry array.

Comment: @CBroe That's a good idea. I'll try to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using just the service to combine the results.  You could solve this by combining the two keys into one:

```
$item->service . $item->type
```

Thus your answer could be done as:

```
$myArr = array_reduce($myArr, function($carry, $item) {  
    $compoundKey = $item->service . '/' . $item->type;
    if(!isset($carry[$compoundKey])) {
        $carry[$compoundKey] = $item;
    } else {
        $carry[$compoundKey]->taskCount += $item->taskCount;
        $carry[$compoundKey]->totalDuration += $item->totalDuration;
    }
    
    return $carry;
});
        
$myArr = array_values($myArr);
```

I would put the '/' or something like it in the key in case you ever have to debug.  Also if there is a chance either part can be null, you need to protect against that (?? '') and in that case I also would add a separator.

Comment: Wow, That's a very clever idea. Worked like charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help